# How to use ESC key to exit full screen mode on TextEdit?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut, textedit

I'm trying to change the ESC key on TextEdit to use it to exit full screen mode.

It's a shortcut I find very convenient in many other parts of the OSX environment, like for folders or on other apps (press ESC to exit full screen), but with TextEdit the ESC key will just prompt you to insert a list of preset words (ie 'I', 'but' etc.). This is personally a feature I have no use for and don't care about, and would much better use the ESC key to exist FS, like on many other apps.

I know of the feature to create a keyboard shortcut for an app in System Preferences, but it won't accept ESC on its own.

Does anyone know of any other way to achieve this? I'm on MacBook Air, Yosemite, French version.
Thanks, Vincent

Comment: <shrug> An application such as Keyboard Maestro.  Maybe Typinator.

Comment: Esc works fine on Mojave. Can't test as far back as Yosemite, but this doesn't work on El Capitan. The universal Ctrl/Cmd/F works for both, though… & you're right, you cannot use Esc on its own as a replacement command. It would cause conflicts.